# Grep string if it has multiple match

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

It was hard to formulate a question, better i will show example.
Txt file has these lines

```
city:state:address
city:state
city:
```

I need to extract strings where

```
a) only one occurrences of : 
b) only one occurrences of : and has value after :
c) two occurrences of :
```

and put these strings to deferent files, so one file will contain all strings with
`city:state:address` second with `city:state` third one `city:`

**Note:** File has many such strings. Not obligatory to create three files in one command. It will be enough one command where i may define how many `:` string should contain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use these invocations of grep and pipe the output into different files:

1. `grep -E "^[^:]+:\s*$" file.txt`
2. `grep -E "^[^:]+:[^:]+$" file.txt`
3. `grep -E "^[^:]+:[^:]+:.*$" file.txt`

It looks for something that is not `:` with the regex `[^:]+`. It uses `^` and `$` at the begin and end to match the whole input line.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for awk, not grep. All you need is:

```
awk -F':' '
    NF==3 { print > "file_c"; next }
    { print > ($2=="" ? "file_a" : "file_b") }
' file
```

and that'll create all the files you want in one pass of your input file.

If you have more fields and more rules just write them all down so they're mutually exclusive, e.g. you could implement the above as:

```
    NF==3           { print > "file_c" }
    NF==2 && $2=="" { print > "file_a" }
    NF==2 && $2!="" { print > "file_b" }
```